# php echo and require syntax

Tags: php, syntax, echo, require

I apologize in advance if this is a needless question.

I've looked around for syntax on php echo and require functions, and multiple pages have different answers. However, each version of the syntax works.

What I want to know is if any of these versions are obsolete, or if one performs slightly better than the other.

```
<?php echo($variable); ?>
<?php echo $variable ?>

<?php require('file.php'); ?>
<?php require 'file.php'; ?>
```

I see them with parentheses, without parentheses, with single quotation marks, without.. etc.

Is there a definitive syntax for each one?

Thank you.

Comment: In these cases, parentheses are just for formatting. You may also want to look into `require_once`

Comment: "_or if one performs slightly better than the other_". Microperformance? Don't worry about it, no parenthesis looks cleaner, I'd just go with that.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by formatting? And thank you for the suggestion with require_once, was actually just reading about it on php.net

Comment: @popsicle As mentioned in one of the answers, neither `echo` or `require` need parentheses. See Phil's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) on `echo`

> [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. **Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.**

---

Both `echo` and `require` are **language constructs**, the same applies to `require`, `include`, `require_once` and `include_path`.

Comment: -0.5 And what about `require`?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Edited reply.

Comment: The important thing to mention here is that both functions use parentheses when passing more than one variable to them.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk false. `echo 1, 2, 3, 4;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Martin That's because it's acting as a concatenation.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk no it isn't. If you want to pull up an strace you'll see 4 `write()` calls.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Good to hear :)

Comment: For clarification, you're saying the following will work?
`<?php require_once '1.php', '2.php', '3.php', '4.php'; ?>` and the same for echo?

Comment: @popsicle No. In case of `echo`, as mentioned in my reply above, *if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses*. As an example, see [this](http://codepad.org/D9ejpem1) link. Now, as for `require` and `require_once`; they can have **atmost** one argument passed to them.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` and `require` aren't `functions`, they're `language constructs` which don't require `parenthesis`.

There's no notable performance differences.

Comment: This does not completely answer the question. *"What I want to know is if any of these versions are obsolete, or if one performs slightly better than the other."*

Comment: Why not? If () are not required, then they are optional.

Comment: How does that excerpt from the manual apply to the performance?

Comment: It doesn't, it was poor grammar. Why do you feel the need to comment and down vote every answer in this thread when you don't know what you're talking about anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses do make a difference. All you need to do is read the fine manual

[`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses

[`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (applies to `require` as well)

> Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument. Take care when comparing return value.

See [Example #4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-140) for how it can make a difference.

I would recommend *not* using parentheses with either construct due to the limitations they impose (`echo`) and the effect on return values (`include`)

Comment: The ***only*** complete and thorough answer. +1